# haskell stack can't find sdl_config? windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, sdl, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install sdl model into haskell. I have this problem and I don't know where to put the sdl_config and how to set it up.

I have tried mutiple ways to get sdl_config working, such as building it with Code::blocks but I never seem to get it to work.

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\stack14648\SDL-0.6.7.0\Setup.lhs, C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\stack14648\SDL-0.6.7.0\.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\setup\Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( C:\sr\setup-exe-src\setup-shim-Z6RU0evB.hs, C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\stack14648\SDL-0.6.7.0\.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\setup\StackSetupShim.o )
Linking C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\stack14648\SDL-0.6.7.0\.stack-work\dist\e626a42b\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring SDL-0.6.7.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
configure: loading site script /usr/local/etc/config.site
checking for sdl-config... no
checking for sdl11-config... no
configure: error: *** SDL not found! Get SDL from www.libsdl.org.
If you already installed it, check it's in the path. If problem remains,
please send a mail to the address that appears in ./configure --version
indicating your platform, the version of configure script and the problem.
```

I want haskell stack to be able to install SDL model into haskell without error.

Comment: IIRC, you have to use `stack exec pacman` to install it.

Comment: Expanding on @arrowd's comment, try running `stack exec -- pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2`. Of course, this only works if you use Stack.